# What's the meaning of 'lay over'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Dictionary says 'lay over' means 'a short stop in a journey', 'stopover', but 
I don't understand this sentence translating 'lay over' as 'stopover'.

Here is the sentence, which is from 'Baker's blue-jay yarn' by Mark Twain:

> And there's yet another thing; in the one little particular of scolding - just good, clean, out-and-out scolding - a blue-jay can ***lay over*** anything, human or divine. Yes, sir, a jay is everything that a man is.

Comment: Damkeng found it. So, to put it shortly, in regard to this question and your question about scolding:  A bluejay is better at scolding than anyone else.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Actually, snailboat was the one who found it in OED. My hat off to snailboat. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

#### 'Lay over' = to excel, to 'put in the shade'

This sense of ***lay over*** is uncommon, as far as I can tell. Oxford English Dictionary (OED) even quotes Mark Twain in the definition of this sense of *lay over*! It means ***to excel*** or ***to 'put in the shade'***.

It's defined in sense **c.** of **57. Lay over** under **Lay** in the first edition of OED (1908):

> c. ? *U.S. colloq.* To excel, to 'put in the shade'. 1869 B. HARTE *Luck Roaring Camp* (1870) 15 They've a street up there in 'Roaring' that would lay over any street in Red Dog. 1876 MARK TWAIN *Tramp Abbr.* (1880) 1. ii. 19 In scolding .. a blue-jay can lay over anything, human or divine.
>
> *(see the image below)*

---

[image: The definition of 'lay over', sense 57c of 'Lay' in OED]

---

#### Reading comprehension

So, how can we understand our sentence in question?

First of all, I've never read this short story (*What Stumped the Bluejays*) by Mark Twain before, and I guessed the meaning of *lay over* wrong at first. Luckily, I found the text [here](http://www.eastoftheweb.com/short-stories/UBooks/WhaStu.shtml). So, I think it's worth to discuss the text a little, enough that we can understand the sentence in the context.

Here is the introduction of the short story. The writer points out that a jay (a bluejay bird) is very good at language:

> Animals talk to each other, of course. There can be no question about that; ...
> [...]
> **There's more to a bluejay than any other creature.** He has got more moods, and more different kinds of feelings than other creatures; and mind you, **whatever a bluejay feels, he can put into language**. And **no mere commonplace language**, either, but rattling, out-and-out book talk - and bristling with metaphor, too - **just bristling!** ...

Soon, the writer convinces us that a bluejay (or a jay) is not only as good as a human; a blue jay is really good at swearing! (Perhaps because a bluejay has lots of bristles (when *bristle* is a noun, it means "a short stiff hair"--*because he's got feathers on him*, according to the story) which makes him "bristling" (*bristle* the verb can either refer to the bristling of animal's fur and feathers or mean to be angry of offended about something) -- a great wordplay, IMHO.)

> You may call a jay a bird. Well, so he is, in a measure - because he's got feathers on him, and don't belong to no church, perhaps; but otherwise **he is just as much a human as you be**. And I'll tell you for why. A jay's gifts, and instincts, and feelings, and interests, cover the whole ground. [...] Now, on top of all this, there's another thing; **a jay can outswear any gentleman in the mines**.

Now we reach the sentence in our question:

> And there's yet another thing; in the one little particular of scolding - **just good, clean, out-and-out scolding** - a bluejay **can lay over anything**, human or divine.

So, a bluejay is not just good at swearing; he's really good at scolding. (***[Scolding](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/scold)*** means "to criticize someone, especially a child, severely and usually angrily for something they have done wrong".) A bluejay can lay over anything or anyone. He's *really good at scolding*. He *excels* at it! He can *put everyone else's scolding in the shade*. In other words, ***bluejays are champions of scolding!***