# Meaning of 'scolding'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

'scolding' means 'speaking angrily to someone because of his or her unpleasant behavior, but that word from the sentence below, I guess, should be translated differently.

Here is the sentence, which is from 'Baker's blue-jay yarn' by Mark Twain:

> And there's yet another thing; in the one little particular of ***scolding*** - just good, clean, out-and-out ***scolding*** - a blue-jay can lay over anything, human or divine. Yes, sir, a jay is everything that a man is.

Comment: Um... nope. That's about what "scolding" means, even in this passage.

Comment: I proposed to close this question as a duplicate of another related question: [What's the meaning of 'lay over'?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/63291/3281), to which I've included a definition of "scolding" (which is the same as what the OP found and what Catija said) in my answer.